# Passing parameters to a different jscript on meteor

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, ionic-framework

I've just started using Meteor with Ionic - and am having difficulty working out how to pass information when attempting to change pages.

```
        <a class='button button-assertive' id="viewContact" data-ion-modal="viewContact" data-id="{{firstName}}">View Contact</a>
```

This is the button that ive created - and my javascript is:

```
Template.addContact.helpers({

  listCont: function () {
   return listCont.findOne({firstName: template.data.id})
  }
});
```

What is the proper way to give the firsName: the actual data? Id love to use the ID that is created behind the scenes too.

Ive attempted with this as an alternative unsuccessfully too:

```
  "click #viewContact": function () {
      alert("test");
      currentContact = Session.get({ _id: this._id });
      Router.go('/viewContact');
      return listCont.findOne({ _id: this._id });
    },
```

Hope this is understandable, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using a router, just define a route that takes a parameter and then navigate to it.

```
Router.go('/viewContact',{_id: this._id});
```

Route:

```
Router.route('/viewContact/:_id', function () {
  var item = listCont.findOne.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  this.render('viewContact', {data: item});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Ive added the router.go to my button

    "click #viewContact": function () {
      Router.go('/viewContact',{_id: this._id});
    },

the Router.route to my Template.viewContact.helpers, although its declaring 2:6 being an unexpected token. (being Router.route)

Am i routing incorrectly ?

Comment: 2:6?? What is the value of `this._id`?